# Time-complexity of cummulative sum of random numbers ( from uniform distribution ) as long as sum is less than 1

Tags: python, random, cumsum

What is the time-complexity of the following loop?

```
import random  
def cummulative_sum():
   a = 0
   while a < 1:
       a += random.random()
   return a
```

What promises me that the loop will stop? after all, random.random() could keep generating 0 all the time ( ofcourse, highly unprobable but still... ). How many times will it run? ( the answer depends on random.random() being a uniform probability, but I can't seem to link the mathematics to the complexity ).

Comment: Time complexity is dependence on size of input. There is no input here, just a distribution of durations.

Comment: Ok, disregard the input. How many times will the loop run? how would you even analyze that?

Comment: Assuming a uniform input distribution, I would expect something that looks like a poisson distribution in the output

Comment: I haven't learned of probability and statistics yet, just very basic stuff in my programming course ( Including usage of random package ). say I want the loop to run till a<b where b is some constant, I'll expect the loop to run 2*b times on average? what about worst case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How many times will it run?

Finding the expected number of iterations for this loop is a tricky math problem. You can see a few solutions in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8508/expected-number-of-0-1-distributed-continuous-random-variables-required-to-sum

Apparently, this was even a question on the 1958 Putnam test (so you know it's a tough one): https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol583.html

> What promises me that the loop will stop?

Nothing! It's true that `random.random()` could return 0s forever, and the function would never terminate. This is reminiscent of a Las Vegas algorithm in some ways, since its expected runtime is finite, but its worst case runtime is unbounded.

---

You can even explore your average runtime experimentally, like so:

```py
import random  
import math

def cummulative_sum():
    a = 0
    iterations = 0
    while a < 1:
        a += random.random()
        iterations += 1
    return iterations

def main():
    total_iterations = 0
    runs = 1_000_000
    for _ in range(runs):
        total_iterations += cummulative_sum()

    print('Average number of iterations:', total_iterations / runs)
    print('e:                           ', math.e)

main()
```